How do I use drones?
I noticed that I'm able to get drones in Planet Crafter, but I'm unclear on what they do or how they work. How do drones function and how can I use them effectively?

Drones need a Drone Station to be useful; once the building is placed, you can add drones to its inventory to make them available for moving things around your world.
Once you have a Drone Station placed, you should be able to find a gear icon in most inventories that allows you to set Supply and Demand for that inventory. So you can have an ore extractor mining uranium somewhere, set to supply uranium, and elsewhere have an Auto Crafter demanding uranium and making Uranium Rods.
Since drones are, IIRC, limited to 1 item each and have a set movement speed, the more drones you have in the station, the faster things can get moved from place to place.
